# Equal Sized Clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to have equal sized 3 clusters for a total of 1000 observations in the form of distance matrix. Below is a sample data of 5 observations for simplicity purpose.

```
    1                  2                3                4           5
1   0             302.0366182    1802.347771    1929.003625      4152.862153
2   302.0366182      0           1502.097742     1629.91035      3966.183353
3   1802.347771   1502.097742          0        137.5130532      3439.08972
4   1929.003625    1629.91035    137.5130532         0           3470.441858
5   4152.862153   3966.183353     3439.08972    3470.441858          0

A <- as.dist(as(Clustering, "matrix"))

Clustering <- scale(Clustering) # standardize variables

# Ward Hierarchical Clustering
d <- dist(Clustering, method*emphasized text* = "euclidean") # for a distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2") 
plot(fit) # display dendogram
cutree(fit, k=3) # cut tree into 3 clusters
# draw dendogram with red borders around the 3 clusters 
rect.hclust(fit, k=3, border="red")
```

How can I get equal sized clusters?

Comment: Clustering is about discovering structure in the data. Usually, these structures will *not* be equal sized.

Comment: You are right Anony but my job requires me to have equal number of company's stores in 24 markets/clusters. You should agree with me that real life companies generally differ from the theories that we study at school. I was just wondering if someone can help me on a code to have equal number of elements (in my case they are my company's stores) in 24 clusters/markets.

Comment: Probably clustering is then the wrong tool. Define a quality criterion, and use a linear constraint solver.

Comment: I can work on solver but the thing is that my evaluation will be done on clustering in R. Working in excel will be an additional task especially meeting the deadline.

Comment: Why would you use excel for such optimization problems? I doubt it can do that. R has better solvers https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: Thanks Anony. If you happen to find any tutorial on solver in R that is specific to my question, please share the link. I know this website is not for tutorials but any help will be greatly appreciated.